# How do I remove unused links?

Tags: navigation

There Drupal links, such as **sitename.com/?q=user** or **sitename.com/?q=user/register** that a user may use for direct login or registration to my site.

What I want to do is to disable those types of direct links.
I have placed my custom blocks for login and sign up in the first page, so if a user hits the URLs above, a strange view of mysite is displayed because it has 2 registration forms: One exists because of my custom block and another exists because Drupal's default registration form

Does anyone know how could I disable or remove all the links of type **sitename.com/link** and the only link that can direct to mysite to be sitename.com?
I know that seems hard because it maybe is not configured in Drupal's layer, but on **HTTP protocol**.
So if that is not possible, can you think of any solution to avoid the above mess?

Answer (score 2):

There is two options using a custom module:

1. Disable access to this path using [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)

   ```
   function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
     unset($items['user/register']);
   }
   ```

   This option will send the user to an *access denied* page.
2. Redirect the user to the home page (or another one)

   ```
   function MYMODULE_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
     $items['user/register']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_go_home';
   }
   function MYMODULE_go_home() {
     drupal_goto('/');
   }
   ```

   Inspiration: [Disabling /node view and other hidden views in Drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515373/872050)

PS: I'm not sure why you want to remove `/user` ? For this special path you can also use [`hook_user_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) module and redirect /user and /user/register to the frontpage. This module allows you to specify a redirect from one path to another path or an external URL, using any HTTP redirect status.